# Using JSoup in a do-while loop, still throwing exceptions

Tags: java, loops, inheritance, jsoup

When I tried to run it and check for errors, I noticed that the do-while loop inside one of my methods that allows re-tries after illegal input is not working when the method was called.

My questions are:
1) Why is the do-while loop in the PageScanner() method not working? 
2) Can you suggest a better way to organize my code?

This is what it currently looks like:

First class: "BulkSpellChecker" (where I tried to organize the code)

```
         import java.io.*;

public class BulkSpellChecker extends ParseCleanCheck {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Let's get started!");

        PageScanner(); // Scan the page and clean it first
        System.out.println("Thanks for using the spell checker!");
    }}
```

Second Class "ParseCleanCheck" (where all of the ugly happens)

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.safety.Whitelist;

public class ParseCleanCheck {

    static Scanner urlInput = new Scanner(System.in);
public static String cleanString = "";
public static String url = "";
public static boolean correct = true;

/**
 * PARSER METHOD
 */
public static void PageScanner() throws IOException {
    System.out.println("Pick a website to scan.");
    System.out.println("Enter a URL, starting with http://");

    do { // This do-while loop allows the user to try again after a mistake
        try {
            url = urlInput.nextLine();
            correct = false;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Incorrect format for a URL.");
        }
    } while (correct == true);

    // This creates a document out of the HTML on the web page
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
    // This converts the document into a string to be cleaned
    String htmlToClean = doc.toString();
    cleanString = Jsoup.clean(htmlToClean, Whitelist.none());
}}
```

disclaimer: I'm fairly new to programming and I apologize if the answer is obvious or if I posted too much code. I can edit and delete the code if necessary.

Comment: You've posted a *lot* of code here. Please reduce it to a [mcve] that *just* demonstrates the problem. (And well done for refraining from asking about the other exception here - one problem per post :)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I edited the code to minimize it now. My problem was just with the parsing method so I realized that I could delete the rest for now.

Comment: Okay, that's looking a lot *more* minimal - but I think it could be reduced further. If you put everything into your `main` method, do away with Jsoup entirely, have just one class, use local variables instead of static variables, do you still see the problem? Can you describe exactly what you see vs what you expect to see? (This sort of diagnostic research is a big part of being a software engineer - I'm hoping this whole process is helping you learn.)

Comment: Your correct naming is backwards.  I would initialize it to false (it's not correct, is it?) then it would only become "True" after they had input a correct URL.  Then it would be "Correct".  Your while clause becomes while(!correct) which reads "while not correct"--that's easier to read.  This will not change your current behavior though, it'll just make it easier to read.

Comment: Well, it could be that you call `PageScanner` when you show `PageScanner2`. If that's not it, could it be that it's working as it should be but not how you expect? I think you might be using inheritance incorrectly here.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils the original code is PageScanner, the "2" in my question was a typo. Sorry. 

Basically, when I run the method on its own in a test class, if i enter an invalid url it will loop and let me try again. when i call the method and try to enter an invalid url it throws an invalid url exception and doesn't loop

Comment: I've solved it now. Thank you to everyone that helped.

Isolating the code, as @Jon Skeet suggested,  helped me narrow down my problem from a big chunk of code to a small block of text. 
Bill K 's advice on fixing my while clause lead me to focus my attention onto that and eventually lead to the answer.

the JSoup URL connector should have remained in the try-block or else the program would have no way of telling whether or not it is valid. Once that was moved, it began to work perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isolating the code helped me narrow down my problem from a big chunk of code to a small block of text. Bill K 's advice on fixing my while clause lead me to focus my attention onto that and eventually lead to the answer. the Jsoup URL connector should have remained in the try-block or else the program would have no way of telling whether or not it is valid. Once that was moved, it began to work perfectly.

In case someone else gets stuck trying to loop jsoup, the solution is here:

```
/**
     * PARSER METHOD
     */
    public static void PageScanner() throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Pick a website to scan.");

        // This do-while loop allows the user to try again after a mistake
        do {
            try {
                System.out.println("Enter a URL, starting with http://");
                url = urlInput.nextLine();
                // This creates a document out of the HTML on the web page
                Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
                // This converts the document into a string to be cleaned
                String htmlToClean = doc.toString();
                cleanString = Jsoup.clean(htmlToClean, Whitelist.none());
                correct = false;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Incorrect format for a URL. Please try again.");
            }
        } while (correct);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Although I'm not sure if this is your problem, Scanner can be difficult to work with, I'd avoid it if possible.  It may not be passing the line to you until the buffer is full.  You can try entering a lot of text and see if it ever responds (I believe this is windows behavior, not really java's and it may behave differently on Linux).  Another test might be to put a System.out.println right after the nextLine and see if it ever returns.  My guess is it won't return from nextLine until you've entered a bunch of characters (regardless of carriage returns).

You MIGHT be able to trick it into returning from nextLine with an end of stream character (I think it's ctrl-d or ctrl-z) but I believe that will close your standard input stream and you won't be able to read from it again.

If it were me, I'd take one of two approaches depending on my requirements.

One way would be to run it as a one-time program.  Put the text you want on the command line and read it in from your main() parameters.  If you fail to connect print an error and exit--the user can resubmit by hitting up-arrow and editing the last line.  Once this works you can write a .cmd (or bash) batch file that launches your Java app so that you don't have to type in that awkward command line every time.

The second would be to use one of the Java input box GUIs.  They boil down to just a few lines of code to give you a pop-up dialog where your user can input his text.

Something like this should work (Didn't double check but I think this is right):

```
  String url = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter a URL to check");
```

IF the first try fails you can just as easily change the text to something like "That URL did not work, please enter a different url to retry" on the second try.

Also if url is null the user hit cancel, so exit.

Comment: Using a java GUI was a great idea, I'll see if i can implement that into my code.
I figured out the problem; I needed the Jsoup connector immediately after the scanner input so that it can be checked for validity while it is still in the loop, otherwise the input would always be considered valid.